# Why does my wrapper not expand beyond a certain height?

Tags: css, flexbox, gif, image-scaling, webflow

To explain it as shortly as possible; I have two pictures inside a wrapper. I want these pictures to retain a ratio 3:2. I want the pictures to just push the next object further down the page. This works fine when below a certain browser width, but above a certain browser width it starts overflowing the wrapper... ? Why does the wrapper div stop growing in height? the max-height is set to: none;

[link](https://www.9tofive.dk/the-last-statement-t-shirt)

I feel like there's something obvious I'm missing here?

[The 'side-by-side-wrapper'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UU2mb.jpg)

[the img with a 3.2 Ratio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oben.jpg)

My thinking is that the img has a certain width defiened by the browser width. And because I've defined the ration to be 3:2 (portrait) it should automatically calculate the height as well.

I've tried giving the wrapper a css property
*
max-height: none !important;*

but it doens't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating the styles for the selector `.project-img-sidebyside-wrapper` like this:

```
.project-img-sidebyside-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}
```

This should resolve the issue of overlapping. I couldn't figure out how to solve it using flex.

Comment: Thank you! It works.. kinda'. I have to set a 'min-height' value for the pictures to load for some reason, but then using the grid layout instead of the flex works so far. Again, Thank you!!!

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if i understand the problem correctly, but if you want to have the menu-wrapper at the top and the content_wrapper at the bottom under 500px you have to remove position: sticky; from menu-wrapper with some media query.